# how to use FormValidation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Is it possible how to display string from controller to view in codeigniter?
im doing a form validation to check if a certain record exists in the database.

here's the code for my controller

```
function create_customer()
        {
            // field name, error message, validation rules
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|callback_username_exists');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('admin/users/admin_form');
            }

            else
            {           
                if($query = $this->usermodel->create_customer())
                {
                        redirect('userslist');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->load->view('admin/users/admin_form.php');            
                }
            }

        }

            function username_exists($key)
        {
            $this->usermodel->username_exists($this->input->post('username'));
        }
```

here's the code for my model

```
function create_customer()
    {
            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password ' => md5($this->input->post('password '))     
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
            return $insert;
    }

    function username_exists($key)
    {
        $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

what i wanted to happen is; how will i show an expected error message something like this "Username already exists" and i want to display it in my view. is this possible? or should i try to do another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can study [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html). But for your better understanding, I will explain the whole thing. Your **Controller** should look like this

```
function create_customer()
{
    // field name, error message, validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|callback_username_exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
       $this->load->view('admin/users/admin_form');
    }
    else
    {           
       if($query = $this->usermodel->create_customer())
       {
           redirect('userslist');
       }
       else
       {
           $this->load->view('admin/users/admin_form.php');            
        }
    }
}

function username_exists($key)
{
    if($this->usermodel->username_exists($key))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_exists', 'User Name already Exists');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Here's the Code for your **Model**

```
function username_exists($key)
{
    $this->db->where('username',$key);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your **View** should contain the following line:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

If you still have problem to understand please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

On controller: 
    `$this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="message">YES!</div>');`

Then just call on your view: `<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>`

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Form Validation class, in view the error messages are present. All you need to call the error message using `form_error()`. For more details please visit http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html.

Also to pass a variable to view, you need to pass it when you call a view to display
`$this->load->view('YOUR_VIEW', array('VARIABLE_NAME' => "VARIABLE_VALUE"));`

Answer (score -1):

You can define a variable in controller class.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        //This variable will be automaticly passed to the view.
        $this->data = "some data";

        $this->load->view('home_main');
    }
```

home_main.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $this->data ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It is an usefull method.

Comment: I think you missed to understand the Question Properly.